# How to make my 19" monitor default display output when I connect it to my netbook?

Tags: display, output

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I set  external monitor as default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34148/how-can-i-set-external-monitor-as-default)

I am new to Linux, so I am still learning tricks and ways of personalisation.

I have Asus Eee PC 1015PEM netbook and 19" monitor. Is it posible that when I connect monitor to VGA port of netbook that monitor become deafult display with resolution 1440x900, and netbook display to turn blank so I can close it? Generaly I want to use netbook like PC case.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Click the Ubuntu button and type and choose Monitors. There after connecting the monitor, you should be able to choose which monitor you want as your default device. You should also be able to turn off the display to a particular monitor from there.

This is just to show you how the monitor preferences window looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have the monitor attached when starting the computer up, it should be used as the main/only display. I have a monitor connected to my laptop through HDMI and this is how it behaves. I also make sure to shutdown with the monitor still connected...so I never disconnect/reconnect the monitor while the machine is powered on.